# Video Capture and implementation Google Cardboard (like Paul Mccartney app)

Tags: android, oculus, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

Regards community

I just want to build a similar app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jauntvr.preview.mccartney),
with my own content of course.

1. How to capture 360 degree video (cameras, format, ingest, audio)?
2. Implementation:

   2.1 Which one `Cardboard` SDK works best for my interests (`Android` or `Unity`)

   2.2 Do you know any blogs, websites, tutorials, samples in which I can    support.

Thank you

Comment: Btw, your question has indeed two separate questions, one of which isn't appropriate for SO and should be posted in another SE site. The other one is very subjective, as what is "best" for your interest is opinion-based. You also asking for links to blogs and tutorials which means you didnt do any research yet, and that is frowned upon here. Please read our FAQ for a guide for posting high quality questions that attract high quality answers.

Answer (score 2):

`MovieTextures` are a great way to do this in `Unity`, but unfortunately `MovieTextures` are not implemented on Android (maybe this will change in `Unity 5`).  See the docs [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html):

For a simple wrap-a-texture-on-a-sphere app, the `Cardboard` Java SDK should work.  But if you would rather use `Unity` due to other aspects of the app, the next best way to do this would be to allocate a `RenderTexture` and then grab the `GL` id and pass it to a native plugin that you would write.

This native code would be decoding the video stream, and for each frame it would fill the texture.  Then `Unity` can handle the rest of the rendering, as detailed by the previous answer.

Comment: MovieTextures are available in Unity5 Personal, so they should be available for building on Android too :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need content, and to record stereo 360 video, you'll need a rig of at least 12 cameras. Such rigs can be purchased for GoPro cams. That's gonna be expensive.

The recently released Unity 5 is a great option and I strongly suggest using it. The most basic way of doing 360 stereo videos in Unity is to create two spheres with MovieTextures showing your 360 video. Then you turn them "inside out", so that they display their back faces instead of the front faces. This can be done with a simple shader, turning on front face culling and removing the mirror effect. Then you place your cameras inside the spheres. If you are using the google cardboard sdk camera rig, put the spheres on different culling layers and make the cameras only see the appropriate spheres. Remember to put the spheres in proper positions regarding the cameras.

There may be other ways to do this, leading to better results, but they won't be as simple. You can also look for some paid scripts/plugins/assets to do 360 video in VR.